# Is is possible for my Waf wscript to call other wscripts in the current directory?

Tags: waf

I am building a project with Waf. It has several third-party dependencies, and I would like to build each dependency from my main `wscript`. My project is organized like this:

```
/boost/
/gtest/
/source/
/waf
/wscript
/wscript_boost
/wscript_gtest
```

Each "dependency" `wscript_*` has commands defined, just like my main `wscript`.

```
def options(opt): pass
def configure(conf): pass
def build(bld): pass
```

If I had put the dependency `wscript` files in the dependency folders, I could just call `opt.recurse('boost gtest')`, but I don't want to mix my files with third-party files.

Is there any way for my `wscript` to call into `wscript_boost` and `wscript_gtest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible in the current Waf implementation ([`waflib.Context.Context.recurse`](https://code.google.com/p/waf/source/browse/waflib/Context.py?spec=svn345f6bc99f54b668aa5b2fc867f450ec6da2d960&r=c3cbd4c35350b4bae24fc3bb15998f16217ac922#282) uses a global `WSCRIPT_FILE` variable).

Though ugly, it *is* possible to hack this at the beginning of your main `wscript`:

```python
import waflib.Context
original_recurse = waflib.Context.Context.recurse

def new_recurse(ctx,*args, **kwargs):
  original_wscript_file = waflib.Context.WSCRIPT_FILE
  try:
    waflib.Context.WSCRIPT_FILE = (original_wscript_file + 
                                   kwargs.pop('suffix', ''))

    original_recurse(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
  finally:
    waflib.Context.WSCRIPT_FILE = original_wscript_file

waflib.Context.Context.recurse = new_recurse
```

Your main `wscript` would the be something like:

```python
def configure(cfg):
  cfg.recurse(suffix='_boost')
  cfg.recurse(suffix='_gtest')
```

Note that there are some side effects, as `WSCRIPT_FILE` is suffixed when you are inside the `wscript_boost` file.

You can also [submit an issue](https://code.google.com/p/waf/issues/list) to the waf project.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that is usually to put a wscript into each subdirectory and to use recurse :

```
/boost/
/boost/wscript
/gtest/wscript
/source/
/waf
/wscript
```

And use recurse :

```
def build(bld):
     # ...
     bld.recurse("boost")
     bld.recurse("gtest")
     # ...
```

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm currently set up. However I do not like mixing my project's files with the third-party dependencies. I want the assurance that my third-party directories match exactly what is provided by the third party.